# Why there is item created and stored in DB within rspec test, but app does not see it stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rspec, httprequest

I've got issue during controller testing in rspec. I created an entity (stored in postgres) and passed the `entity.id` as `HTTP request` parameter. I can see that the entity was stored into DB within the test, but controller did not see it.

All DB request happened within one transaction, so I thought it will be the problem.

I've got bunch of similar tests, so there is no problem with the DB connection and anything like that.

I tried to move `create :entity` to before block, and loaded it to request as `Entity.all.first.id`.
Using `let!(:entity) {create :entity}` was also useless. Taking it out from contexts too.

```
// notifications_controller_spec.rb
context 'with an entity' do
  it 'renders the list of notifications' do
    entity = create :entity

    pp Entity.all // returns array with stored entity

    get :index, entity: entity.id

    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    expect(response).to render_template 'index'
  end
end



//notifications_controller.rb
def index

  pp Entity.all // returns empty array

  defaults_entity
  return render 'welcome_no_entity' if @entity.nil?

  @notifications = NotificationDecorator.decorate_collection(
    Notification::EntityScopedQuery.
      new(@entity.id, { order: { created_at: :desc } }).
      all
  )
 end
```

I would expect to see stored the same entity as in the test.

There will be probably some stupid mistake. Thx for help.

EDIT1:

```
// create entity
INSERT INTO "entities" ("name", "type", "customer_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "test"], ["type", "complex"], ["customer_id", 514911], ["created_at", "2019-01-24 08:43:00.145471"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-24 08:43:00.145471"]]
// select in test
SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities"
```

There is no other log like `SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities"`, even when there should be. I can also say, select is from the test.

Comment: Is entity in your test properly persisted? `entity.valid? && entity.persisted?`

Comment: In `defaults_entity`: `@entity = params.deep_symbolize_keys[:entity]`. But it is just an ID. Using that ID, entity is loaded from DB. And that is the problem. There is not entity stored in the DB on controllers site.

Comment: Actually, ID is passed ok, strange. I couldn't be passed when the entity was not created before

Comment: `pp entity.valid? && entity.persisted? // true`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that we use gem `Multitenant` within the controller. So in the controller it does not make select like `SELECT * FROM entities WHERE id = ?`, but `SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."customer_id" = $1`

And `customer_id` was not defined, so it was totally random.

Fixed in test: `entity = create :entity, customer_id: customer_id`

Comment: Ah, multi-tenant app. Critical detail. :)

Comment: Yup, sorry, I did not even know about that.